# rails thinking sphinx,How do i set delta to true after reindexing?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, thinking-sphinx

When I run a reindexing task(rake ts:reindex), it automatically sets delta value to false.But I definitely want delta indexing working after reindexing. So I want to set the delta value back to 'true'. How can I do that??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need delta indexing after your reindex as the main index will be up to date and complete. Your model should only set the delta flag to true after your next update, which is when your main index will be incomplete.

Answer (score 1):

Thinking Sphinx will automatically set delta to true when you make changes to a model instance.

The only cases where this is *not* the case is when you're actually changing an association instance, instead of the indexed model, or you're changing the indexed model in some way which doesn't fire the callbacks. `#update_attribute` (note: singular) does not fire callbacks. `#save` and `#update_attributes` do.

So: how are you changing your model instances? Is delta indexing not occurring when you make those changes?